# What do I put in the visit dict passed to my user-defined __deepcopy__ function?

Tags: python, deep-copy

I need to define my own deepcopy function for one of my classes. The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) says that the function `__deepcopy__()` is passed a memo dictionary for tracking which objects have already been copied, to avoid getting caught in coping a recursive object. However it doesn't say what to put in the dictionary. Do I put objects in, or object IDs? How do you use it? I can't find any site that explains it, except [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=Chr1NDlUcI8C&pg=PA220&lpg=PA219&dq=python+user-defined+copy&source=bl&ots=OAIDxjgTDn&sig=OiEufwhAuMDg_vJQZI6nhmjQ8lk&hl=en&ei=8xfQTL_qNtHusga1oJGKAg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=10&ved=0CEkQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=python%20user-defined%20copy&f=false) book that says that it need not be used, except to pass it to other invocations of `__deepcopy__`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be consistent with the built-in `copy.deepcopy` behavior, you should use the `id` of the object as a key.

**More Details:**

While you can often get away with using a different key scheme (such as the object itself, if it's hashable), as long as you're consistent, you can still run into trouble. Frequently `__deepcopy__` is implemented by calling `copy.deepcopy` on some contained attributes. If *you* add items directly to `memo`, you have to be *certain* the keys won't collide with items added by `copy.deepcopy`, which adds keys generated by `id`, which are integers.

So if you use a different key scheme, such as using objects directly as keys, you can't ever add any integer objects.

**Bottom Line:**

It's much easier to just use `id` and not have to worry about the exceptions above.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, with thanks to @Jon-Eric:

What I understand from the example shown at http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/copy/, is that you use `self` as the key, and the copied object as the value. Then, when it is attempted to copy this object(`self`) again, one can check the memo dictionary to see whether it has already been copied, and return the reference to the copy, `memo[self]`.

Comment: Sorry I mislead you with the link initially. I added more details of why it's best/easiest to use the `id` of the object.